# Why my code only outputs part of the input string?

Tags: c++, string, printing

thank you for reading. I am a new programmer in an introductory programming class, and I only have a month's worth of training in C++. I have tried to fix this code with many approaches, but I don't know why it only prints one word of my input string:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void printThetxt(string);
string inputText(string);
    int main() {
        string x;
        printThetxt(inputText(x));
        system("pause");
            return 0;
}
void printThetxt(string y) {
    cout << y << endl;
}
string inputText(string x) {
cout << "Type in your string: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}
```

Please tell me why this code only prints one piece of the input string? Thank you!!

Comment: Because `operator >>` only reads until a whitespace.

Comment: surely you could have formulated the question better... "part"? :)

Comment: do you want to read a line?

Comment: I want it to output what I input. And I want to create two separate functions: one for input and the other for output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
cin >> x;
```

with:

```
std::getline(std::cin, x);
```

because formatted input stops at whitespace.